# Behavior of JPA ORM of two entities with different CascadeType parameter?

Tags: jpa, orm, mapping, entity

I have a question regarding the JPA OR mapping between two persistent entities with a different CascadeType parameter on their annotations.

To clarify things, here is a simple example:

```
@Entity
public class Article
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long    id;

    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private Author  author;

    // Getters and Setters follow here
}
```

_

```
@Entity
public class Author
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long            id;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, 
        orphanRemoval = true )
    private List< Article > articles;

    // Getters and Setters follow here
}
```

As you can see, the "author" property has a different CascadeType set
(CascadeType.REFRESH) then the "articles" property (CascadeType.ALL). At first, I thought that a different CascadeType for the same property mapping is not allowed - but I tried it, and it is allowed.

Now, what I would like to know is, how does this behave? And makes such a (artifical) example any sense at all (as you see, this is more a theoretical question)?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cascade = CascadeType.XXX` means: when you do the XXX operation on this object, automatically do the same XXX operation on the object(s) referenced by the association.

So, in your case, if you persist/merge/delete an article, it will also persist/merge/delete its author. This is thus very questionable. I don't think you really want that.

And when you'll refresh an author, it will also refresh its articles.

Note that if you refresh an article, it will refresh its author (because of CascadeType.ALL), and since the association form author to articles also has the REFRESH cascade type, it will also refresh all the articles of the author.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Due to the DB constraints, deleted an article would throw an error, if an Author is referenced by one more Article, right? (The Author can't be deleted). With the cascade on both side, could that cause an infinite refresh/delete/persist-loop?

Comment: Yes, it would throw an error. But this is clearly a sign that the cascade ALL doesn't make sense. It won't cause an infinite loop, because Hibernate is smart enough to know the a cascade has already been applied to an entity.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I learned that it is not a good idea to use CascadeType.ALL all the time (but when I omit the DELETE operation, their might be orphans left in the DB). Just one more question (hopefully ;): What exactly means REFRESH here? I can imagine what PERSIST, DELETE etc. ist, but what must be done in Java to result in a REFRESH operation?

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29